# Criei uma tabuada em javascript e estou com problemas

Tags: javascript

Quando faço o calculo da tabuada ele aparece na tela tudo certinho, más quando vou fazer de outro numero ele junta com o resultado da tabuada anterior e fica aumentando os resultados...

Eu esperava que cada calculo de um número que fizesse ele aparece na tela e quando quisesse fazer de outro número ele resetasse o campo.

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("botao-tabuada");
const saida = document.querySelector(".campoTabuada");

botao.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let n = Number(document.getElementById("numeroDaTabuada").value);
    if(n <=0) {
        console.log("Digite um numero maior que 0!");
    }else{
        saida.classList.replace("campoTabuada", "campoTabuadaON")
        c=1
        while(c<=10){
            var calc = `${n} * ${c} = ${n*c}`
            var resultado = document.createElement("p");
            resultado.innerHTML = calc
            saida.appendChild(resultado);
            c++
        }
        }
    }
)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 70vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  box-shadow: 0.3px 0.3px 15px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

main form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

.formulario {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 7px;
}

.label {
  color: white;
}

.titulo {
  color: white;
}

.inputTabuada {
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 2.7vh;
  padding: 4px;
}

.buttonTabuada {
  width: 5vw;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.buttonTabuada:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.campoTabuada {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  display: none;
}

.campoTabuadaON {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Exercicios</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="titulo">Tabuada luscaDev</h1>
      <form>
        <div class="formulario">
          <label class="label">Digite o numero da tabuada que deseja:</label>
          <input type="number" name="numero" id="numeroDaTabuada" class="inputTabuada">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Calcular" class="buttonTabuada" id="botao-tabuada">
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="campoTabuada"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que acontece é que foi criado o elemento  `p` com os resultados  e passado para  `saida` depois  o que acontece é que não apaga  `p` anteriores antes.

Comment: acho que assim, antes de `saida.classList.replace("campoTabuada", "campoTabuadaON")`  em cima dele no bloco *else* ele limpa o valor... `saida.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Na primeira linha do evento apenas coloque `saida.textContent = ''`

Answer (score 0):

Tente limpar o conteúdo antes de iniciar seu preenchimento

`document.getElementsByClassName('campoTabuadaON').innerHTML = '';`

Comment: ainda não consegui :(

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

nessas linhas do teu código JS, acrescente:

}else{
saida.classList.replace("campoTabuada", "campoTabuadaON")
c=1
saida.innerHTML = '' (limpará teu box antes de mostrar uma nova tabuada)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).